# Slice vs filter in redux delete action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

From `Redux` documentation, I know, that we never should mutate state and that's why we should use `concat` and `slice` methods, so I ended up with following reducer(most of actions removed for simplification):

```
export default function blocks(state = [], action) {  
    switch (action.type) {
        case DELETE_BLOCK:
          var index = state.findIndex(e => e.id === action.blockId);
          return [...state.slice(0, index), ...state.slice(index + 1)];
        default:
          return state;
}
```

In my case I don't have index of element I want to delete, so can I use `filter`? Like this:

```
export default function blocks(state = [], action) {  
    switch (action.type) {
        case DELETE_BLOCK:
          return state.filter(e => e.id !== action.blockId);
        default:
          return state;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`filter` does not mutate the state, it returns a new `Array` so there is nothing wrong here.

We try to avoid `filter` when we are dealing with `immutable` data since it always returns a new reference, breaking the reference equality check `===`. But if you don't use this kind of reference by trying to return the previous state reference if you think the state didn't change (and I think you're not doing this, it's ok), you don't need to worry about using `filter`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the reducer is a normal JavaScript function, it is very easy to write tests for it. You just give it a `stateBefore`and an `action` and check if it returns the expected `stateAfter`. You can call something like [deep-freeze](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-freeze) on your `stateBefore` then your test will fail if you accidentally mutated the state. The [Getting Started with Redux](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux) video series shows this technique.